# Tensorflow: About the Variable value after Session run?

Tags: variables, tensorflow

In Tensor, I don't understand the value of Variable. Below is my code, I think after I do

```
  sess.run()
```

The value of **W** should be calculated, however, After print it , I find it didn't change.

The code is an  [MNIST](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) example code from TensorFlow website. Anyone can explain why **W** doesn't change?

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_dat/",one_hot=True)

x= tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,784])#need input x

W= tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))

b= tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y= tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W)+b)


y_= tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,10])#need input y

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_mean(y_*tf.log(y),reduction_indices=[1]))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
    batch_xs,batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={x:batch_xs,y_:batch_ys})

ww=W.eval(sess)
print(ww)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, when I run your code, the output I get looks like this

```
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ...,
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

But you have to realize, that W is 784 by a 100 elements, this display only shows you a few values at the start and end of that. And for most images in MNIST, the first and the last few pixels are not going to be significant (the actual important data is somewhere in the middle, where the actual digit is drawn, right?). But if I change the print statement to

```
print(ww.min(), ww.max())
```

I get this output

-0.330358 0.429428

Which means that some weights are being trained, as expected.

Comment: I see, actually, W is changed .Thanks

Comment: Printing min and max doesn't really tell you much, but if you print a sum of absolute values of W you can see it as a measure of how much your weights have been trained, how far you got from the original zeroes. Have fun, machine learning is awesome.